# click function not rendering the page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to retrieve PNR details but the click function runs into a timeout exception. What could be the possible issue that causes this timeout?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:/Chrome driver/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("link")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='PNRId']"))).send_keys("QPDYUX")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='GstRetrievePageInteraction']"))).click()


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "gst-invoice-list.list-inline")))

elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "gst-invoice-list.list-inline")
```

It gives following error `TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000 (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141)`

How can I move forward with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to stop the website from knowing it's a bot.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:/Chrome driver/chromedriver.exe',options=options)
```

Now for the following:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("link")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='PNRId']"))).send_keys("QPDYUX")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='GstRetrievePageInteraction']"))).click()
elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gst-invoice-list.list-inline")))
for elem in elements:
    print(elem.text)
```

Outputs:

```
GST Invoice No. View/Print
MH1202106AB57221 View Invoice Print Invoice
MH2202106AB78553 View Invoice Print Invoice
```

Comment: It gives an error to add that executable needs to be in path ```WebDriverException: 'chromedriver.exe,options=options' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home```. Does the options part of the code needs to be edited?

Comment: Hi Arundeep, when I updated the line as ```from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options=Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:/Chrome driver/chromedriver.exe',options=options)``` and then it worked.

Comment: Forget the ' by accident.

Comment: If we want the browser to not pop up i.e. be headless. Is it possible that it won't run? As I've used the headless argument with which the files are not downloading, but by excluding it the browser pops, and the files are downloaded. Why could this possibly happen?

Comment: Sometimes headless can cause errors. Try wrapping it in a try except and see if you can spot any errors.

Comment: It hits the browser as I have given one incorrect value that displays "Invalid Details" and it fetches that part correctly. But for correct values, it must go ahead and download zip files. It's not showing any error, it is just somehow not moving ahead when the correct values are entered may be.